# Macro doesn't show up in the macro list

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a macro to refresh data, and I saved it in excel enabled macro format, but once I close the file and reopen the same file, the macro doesn't appear in the list. I usually run in through Power Automate Cloud, and every day I have to face the same problem. The macro doesn't appear in the list, but when I search it in macro list, it can be run but the macro still doesn't appear.

I have tried to recreate the new file, I tried to replace the file with the backup file, I also already tried to create the new macro and replace the old macro, but the problem only fixed temporarily, the same problem still appears after I run the macro for several times.

Can someone please help me..

Comment: maybe when "Save As Excel" the excel extension is still .xlsx not .xlsm,

Comment: Does the macro have any arguments?

Comment: If the module has Private Module at the top or Private Sub Macro_Name then you cannot run from the macro list. Removing private will allow you to see it in the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the Macro in the VBA window but not in the Macros window from the Developer tool bar, open the file from excel using "open and repair".  I have been seeing this a lot since December and it has worked for every client I have tried this with.

Answer (score -2):

if everything else seems fine (file format, vba coding, etc.), try opening the file from excel using option "open and repair.".

Comment: OP did not mention any issues with opening the file.